Animate pseudo element ::before on hover
I have the below structure and I want to animate that once I hover over h1, I have below css which doesn't work not sure where I am doing things wrong.
How can I animate with CSS only as I don't want to use JS? The animation could be scaled or skewed.
CodepenCode


.wrapper{
  width:200px;
  margin:100px auto;
}
.wrapper h1::before {
  content: url('https://i.ibb.co/Bg4jS5B/hat-1-e1713504486338.png'); 
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -25px; 
  margin-top: -35px; 
  width:30px;
  position: absolute;
  /*filter: brightness(0) invert(1);*/
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.wrapper h1::before:hover {
  cursor:progress;
  transform: scale(1.2); 
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>About Us</h1>
</div>




You :hover part is wrong here, use it like this:


.wrapper{
  width:200px;
  margin:100px auto;
}

.wrapper h1::before {
  content: url('https://i.ibb.co/Bg4jS5B/hat-1-e1713504486338.png'); 
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -25px; 
  margin-top: -35px; 
  width:30px;
  position: absolute;
  /*filter: brightness(0) invert(1);*/
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.wrapper h1:hover::before {
  cursor: progress;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>About Us</h1>
</div>




I was doing it other way round.
